# How can I use Math.X functions with LINQ?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a simple table (SQL server and EF6)  **Myvalues**, with columns **Id** & **Value** (double)

I'm trying to get the sum of the natural log of all values in this table.  My LINQ statement is:

```
            var sum = db.Myvalues.Select(x => Math.Log(x.Value)).Sum();
```

It compiles fine, but I'm getting a RTE:

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Log(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

What am I doing wrong/how can I fix this?

FWIW, I can execute the following SQL query directly against the database which gives me the correct answer:

```
select exp(sum(LogCol)) from
    (select log(Myvalues.Value) as LogCol From Myvalues 
) results
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ tries to translate `Math.Log` into a SQL command so it is executed against the DB.

This is not supported.

- The first solution (for SQL Server) is to use one of the existing [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). More specifically, [`SqlFunctions.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd487087%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- The other solution is to retrieve all your items from your DB using `.ToList()`, and execute `Math.Log` with LINQ to Objects (not LINQ to Entities).

Answer (score 3):

As EF cannot translate `Math.Log()` you could get your data in memory and execute the function form your client:

```
var sum = db.Myvalues.ToList().Select(x => Math.Log(x.Value)).Sum();
```