# Make Math.Log work in an Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

How can I make this orderby code work thisEntity Framework query

This is the orderby part of the query

```
orderby (double)b.score * Math.Pow( (1 + Math.Log(b.total_votes)), 0.2)
```

I get this exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Log(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: How many records are you looking at fetching?

Comment: If you don't need the sorting to happen in the db, you can just call `ToList()` to fetch the results before sorting.

Comment: @sachinabout about 10

Comment: I am not working with math for a long time, but I am just wondering, why to  use this complex ordering? If I am not mistaken `a*b` is always greater than `a * Math.Pow((1 + Math.Log(b)), 0.2)`, no matter how you change the `a` and `b`. So you will get same results if you simply order by `a*b`. Please correct me, if I miss something

Comment: @AdilMammadov I'm checking this out

Comment: @IdanShechter cheked myself, there can be differences. You can look at fiddle test [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/30jBFv).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework tries to translate `Math.Log` function into SQL so that it could be executed against the DB but it doesn't know how to do that for Math.Log.

- One solution is to retrieve all your items into memory using
  `.ToList()`, and execute `Math.Log` in memory using LINQ to Objects.
- Another solution is to use the existing `SqlFunctions.Log`.

This is how you could write your orderby:

```
orderby (double)b.score * Math.Pow((1 + SqlFunctions.Log(b.total_votes) ?? default(double)), 0.2)
```

And if there are just 10 records, this is how you can sort in memory:

```
from b in _dataContext.MyTypes.ToList() orderby (double)b.score * Math.Pow((1 + Math.Log(b.total_votes)), 0.2) select b;
```

Comment: what is the type of total_votes? Try casting b.total_votes to double.

Comment: I cast to double and after I run the code, I get this exception: The specified method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double] Log(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' on the type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression. My code: orderby (double)b.score * Math.Pow((1 + System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.Log((double)b.total_votes) ?? default(double)), 0.2). Total Votes is of type long.

Comment: I think you can go with 2nd approach as you're saying that there are only 10 records.

Comment: what .MyTypes.ToList() means?

Comment: The returned results is a new type (I made a class for it called sortedResults)

Comment: I was using MyTypes for a placeholder as I didn't know your type :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of same questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097671/how-can-i-use-math-x-functions-with-linq), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354716/linq-to-ef-unsupported-functions), etc.
Try to use [`SqlFunctions.Log`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx)